# ActionBar implementation

Tags: android-layout, android

which is better to use, GreenDroid, ActionBarSherlock or the ActionBarCompat library?
i'm really having problems in making my app interface for this feature.

Answer (score 2):

```
//use your custom xml view to show your actionbar

View actionBarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar_custom_view, null);
actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarView);
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

Comment: kinda lost here, what do you mean by this custom xml?

Comment: create your own layout for your action bar.

Answer (score 0):

A simple thing is to do your own BUT if you really want it you could try actionbarsherlock, best is always a question about preference but I use sherlock. With your own you don't have some of the small quirks which comes with the bigger libraries.